# How to calculate joint distribution of two linear combinations of variables

Tags: convolution

Suppose 
X = a*U + b*V, 
Y = c*U + d*V. a, b, c, and d are constant. U and V are independent with known pdf, e.g. f(u) and g(v). We know that the pdf of X and Y are the convolution of f and g, but what is the joint distribution of X and Y? I can find the answer for only the case if U and V are normal distributed, but is there any answer if they are not normal?

Comment: Use MathJax to format your questions: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/787310

Comment: Suppose $X = aU + bV, Y = cU + dV$ where $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are constant. $U$ and $V$ are independent with known pdf, e.g. $f(u)$ and $g(v)$. We know that the pdf of $X$ and $Y$ are the convolution of $f$ and $g$, but what is the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$? I can find the answer for only the case if $U$ and $V$ are normal distributed, but is there any answer if they are not normal?